# Changing format using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="6267973685" /> Enter number like this and in next field it will display like this
<input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" value="(626) 797-3685" />
```

I want this to be done using JavaScript i had tried this a lot but not find any success please help me in it.

Comment: try this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: made a demo with you code .. http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/3v90yq3v/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this nice light weight plugin 
**[Masked input plugin for the jQuery](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)**

```js
$("#textfield").mask("(999) 999-9999");
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//digitalbush.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>


<input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" value="6267973685" />
<br/>
Enter number like this and in next field it will display like this
<br/>
<input name="textfield2" type="text" id="textfield2" value="(626) 797-3685" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `oninput` , `onfocus` event , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/(^\d{3})/` to match first three digits , `/(\s\d{3,3})(?!-{1}|$)/` to match three digits following space character not followed by `"-"` or end of input string ; setting `maxlength` attribute to `14` at `input type="text"` element

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[name=textfield]");
input.oninput = input.onfocus = function() {
  this.value = this.value
    .replace(/(^\d{3})/, "($1) ")
    .replace(/(\s\d{3,3})(?!-{1}|$)/, "$1-")
}

input.focus()
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="textfield" type="text" id="textfield" 
    value="6267973685" maxlength="14" />
  <input type="reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: can we change on focus to on click

Comment: @Harsimransingh _"can we change on focus to on click"_ Yes